# Configurable attribute selection dependency in product view page

Tags: configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

I have two configurable attributes and I want their selection not to be dependent, as select first option one and then option two.

Is it possible to select the options at any order, thus without any dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Everything is.

But not with the JS magento provides.

The problem is, magento builds a JS which has this way:

1. choose option A
2. check what options are possible
3. show options
4. A = B
   5 start with 1.

so to achieve this you need to change most of the code to create a complete graph which options are possible with the yet made choices.

I wouldn't recommend this. It is a lot of work and if you think about the order, I think most of the problems can be discussed and not implemented.

#### Example

You have shirts, they have a size a color and a printing.

I think it is clear, that you first choose the size, because for whom you buy this shirt, the size is fixed. The second choice is a business decision but both is right if you ask me.

Comment: It makes perfectly sense what you are saying, and to be honest that's what I was expecting to be the case. However, there are cases where the configurable attributes size & colour are not dependent nor do you have to choose them in a certain order. Thus, all the products (for a certain attribute-set) come in 3 sizes and 5 colours. How do you get to that final combination should not be important in this case. But having a look at configurable.js I understand what you are saying.

Comment: What you can do is use custom options. But then you loose the inventory of you products. But this way you have no dependencies.